# masonry layout problems after removing then appending items

Tags: jquery-masonry, masonry

I'm playing around with masonry.js for a gallery/album view.

I've succesfully used the script to display a thumbnail of albums. When the user clicks the thumbnail I want the album thumbnails to be removed and then replaced with the thumbnails of the images within the album.

The album images are passed to the script via ajax and are in html format

I can remove the items using this code `$container` is a jquery object of the masonry container:

```
var obj = $('.item');
$container.masonry('remove',obj);
$container.masonry('reloadItems');
$container.masonry('layout');
```

I then append the new thumbnails using this script - `data` is the html of the new elements.

```
var $newItems = $(data);

$container.append($newItems).masonry('appended', $newItems);

$container.masonry('reloadItems');
$container.masonry('layout');
```

This loads the new thumbnail elements and organises the layout. However because of the append it places them at the bottom of where the removed thumbnails were.

If I use prepend the images are placed at the top of the element as expected but  I'm then left with loads of white space where the removed items were.

I've also tried `html()` to insert the new items - a layout is applied but the height of the container becomes inconsistent and some items overlap the bottom of the container.

So:

1. How can I remove items and clean up the layout
2. How can I add new items and clean up the layout

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Having the same issue, and saw a related issue here https://github.com/desandro/masonry/issues/381:

```
$container.masonry('remove',obj);
$container.masonry();
```

This seemed to work a little bit better for me.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is solved in the new version. Following code snippet worked for me (I'm using Masonry version 4.1.1).

```
var $newItems = $(data);
var $obj = $('.item');

$grid.masonry( 'remove', $obj);
$grid.append($newItems);
$grid.masonry( 'appended', $newItems ).masonry('layout');
```

Even here, calling `layout` method is mandatory. Not calling `layout` method will append new items in the bottom of the page.

Comment: I was having this same issue with an initially empty grid failing to properly layout the first group of appended elements but successfully laying out all subsequent appends; this very last layout call is what fixed it. There must be something about Masonry's 'appended' function that doesn't work properly if you're appending to a grid layout that contains no grid items; you can see in the CSS that the initial grid items that failed to layout were lacking CSS left/top values.